# How to retrieve sorted entries from many-to-many rich association in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

Let's say I have a many-to-many rich association between queues and dudes:

Queue:

```
has_many in_queue_positionings
has_many dudes, through: in_queue_positionings
```

Dude:

```
has_many in_queue_positionings
has_many queues, through: in_queue_positionings
```

InQueuePositioning has `position` column in the table and

`scope :sorted, lambda { order('BY position ASC') }` defined in the model. Let's assume that I always need to access `queue.dudes` sorted by `positions`.

I can access dudes like this:

```
queue.in_queue_positionings.sorted.each { |pos| pos.dude }
```

But this method is ugly(and it might also be slow). So how can this problem be solved elegantly and efficiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Should't use `Queue` because maybe it conflict with `Queue` in
   `Thread`
2. I'm not sure we can use scope in `has_many` association, but you can
   try this

InQueuePositioning

```
class InQueuePositioning < ...
  belongs_to :queue
  belongs_to :dude
end
```

Queue

```
class Queue < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :in_queue_positionings, ->{order("position ASC")}
  has_many :dudes, through: :in_queue_positionings
end
```

and call it

```
queue.dudes
```

Comment: Queue is just an example to describe the problem btw, not the actual model name.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
queue.dudes.order('in_queue_positionings.position')
```

We have the following in our app:

```
Grant:
has_many :programs, dependent: :destroy
has_many :klasses, through: :programs

Program:
has_many :klasses, dependent: :destroy
```

And the following works:

```
grant.klasses.order('programs.name desc')
```

And it avoids N+1

Comment: Sorry, but can you explain what does avoiding N+1 mean?

Comment: Sorry for being cryptic. I meant it eager loads. Refer to http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html